# API authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have the task to build a new API. The API will mainly be used by tablet applications.
I'm thinking of using the new ASP WebApi.
My biggest concern however is the security part. Because the apps will be build by third-party companies, we do not want that usercredentials will be entered in their application, but redirected to our site (authenticationserver).
I have done some researching and I came accross OAuth 2.0. For working with mobile devices and tablets it's probably the best to work with the 'autohorization code flow' principle -correct me if I'm wrong-.

Am I thinking in the right direction or are their simpler authentication systems to achieve my goal?
Are their any frameworks (.NET) available (or documentation) how to create an Authentication Server and how to use it in the Asp webapi?
Is it easy these days to implement oauth2.0 in an IOS app?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 authz code based grant is suitable when client app is a Web application. Will the apps that are going to be built by third party all be Web applications? There are HTTP redirects involved in that flow.

In OAuth 2.0, there is a client, there is a resource server (Web API in your case) and there is an authorization server. There is no such thing as Authentication server. Are you referring to some thing else?

Comment: Our first client will be an iphony and ipad app. In the future there will also be some web applications that will be using the API.
I did mean the Authorization server, what was I thinking :).

Thanks for your reply!